# VMware Player crashes while playing youtube.com videos

Tags: vmware, crash, youtube

Why does the newest VMware Player crash down while playing videos on youtube.com?

It starts playing the video and then crashes down completely. I always have to reset the player to go on working.

Does anyone know why this occurs?

Comment: Is it just me, tired after this looong week of work? This question  *actually* seems funny.

Comment: your question seems a little bit ambiguous...can you clarify?

Comment: what OS in VMware?

Answer (score 0):

I know this really isnt a fix, but sense you just seem to have the problem with youtube you could try and go here [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/html5) and sign up for the html5 version of their player, you shouldn't have any problems